# Server Connection in Android Application

Tags: android

How can i connect to the server in Android . Give me Some code it will really helpful for me .

Answer (score 4):

```
Socket socket = new Socket("1.1.1.1", 1111);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
out.println("test");
socket.close();
```

Don't forget to add the

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Use Http connection.Try googling it you can find a lot of examples

A few that i found...

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/05/http-connection-using-threads-handlers.html

http://androidsamples.blogspot.com/2009/06/how-to-use-http-connection-saxparser.html